# Как встроить ffmpeg в установочный файл electron или подкачать при установке приложения

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, electron

Привет.
Я сейчас пишу приложение на electron, в нем я использую fluent-ffmpeg (своего рода обертка над ffmpeg), нужно это для конвертирования в mp4 c webm.

**А теперь к проблеме** :
насколько я знаю обертка работает только с установленным ffmpeg...

Как я могу встроить ffmpeg в установочный файл, или подкачать во время установки самого приложения, подскажите пожалуйста.

PS: или подскажите другой вариант конвертирования в mp4 и mp3 с webm

Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-static

Comment: можно по подробнее, я не понимаю что мне делать с ffmpeg-static
Сейчас я использую fluent-ffmpeg и все работает. Но после того как я соберу в билд через electron-builder выбивает ошибку о том что ffmpeg не найден, вот она "Cannot find ffmpeg
    at /Users/Krot/Desktop/screencap/dist/mac/DesCap.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:136:22"

Comment: `npm install --save ffmpeg-static`

Comment: Я не настоько тупой.. что делать дальше?
Что писать в main процессе, как подрубить все это и юзать?

Answer (score 1):

По странному стечению обстоятельств, тоже занимаюсь на данный момент подобным. В частности использую electron и fluent ffmpeg. Ваша проблема решается очень просто. С официального сайта качаем исполнительные файлы для windowos например. Берем из архива папку bin. И в js файле после инициализации ffmpeg, с помощью команды `Ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(path)` указываем путь до ffmpeg.exe и все работает.

Comment: В принципе я понял, большое спасибо.
Как я понял мне нужно подрубить fluent-ffmpeg через require, а уже потом Ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(путь к скачанному файлу exe  с оф. сайта ffmpeg) верно?
Буду еще более признателен если покажите как это выглядит в коде.

Comment: Именно так. В коде ничего сверхъестественного.
`var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg'),
      command = ffmpeg();
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('./bin/ffmpeg.exe');`

Comment: Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: Сейчас я работаю на MacOS. Во время разработки все хорошо. Но после того как я соберу приложение через electron-builder и попытаюсь конвертировать видео, выбивает
 Error: spawn ./ffmpeg ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9). 
Подрубил так
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('./ffmpeg')

Comment: Я думал, что это из-за того что я не указал формат. Написал ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('./ffmpeg.exec'). Ситуацию это не спасло. Но теперь  в разработке тоже не работает, выбивает ту же ошибку.

Comment: Для Mac вероятно не exe, для каждой платформы свой ffmpeg подключать нужно.

Comment: Я качал с офф сайта, если я не ошибаюсь там был формат exec.
В любом случаи спасибо.
Если не секрет, над каким проектом работаете?

Comment: Над странной штукой с названием Видеобудка. Софт для записи поздравлений. ffmpeg в частности используется для склейки аудио дорожки и видео( оно проходит через canvas чтобы на него в реальном времени эффекты можно наложить), а так же для выбора и склейки отдельных поздравлений в видео ряд.